# Atualizar a página ao excluir

Tags: html, jquery

Tenho esta função para criar um alerta antes de eliminar e chamo-a no botão:

```js
function ConfirmDelete() {
  return confirm("Tem certeza de que deseja excluir esta Requisição?");
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" Onclick="return ConfirmDelete()">Excluir</button>
```

Funciona corretamente, mas não atualiza a página quando elimina a linha. Como faço para quando eliminar uma linha, atualize a página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para atualizar a página você pode usar

```
function ConfirmDelete() {
 location.reload();
 return confirm("Tem certeza de que deseja excluir esta Requisição?");
}
```

Talvez isso já resolva seu problema, caso seja só atualizar a página.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da função ConfirmDelete() você pode inserir o seguinte:

```
location.reload(true);
```

A flag 'true' serve para ele recarregar a página com a versão do servidor, caso deixe sem o parâmetro true, ele irá pegar a última versão em cache.